# Is it possible to mask headers or payload values like passwords?

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I am thinking of integrating spring-cloud-sleuth in our project at work but we have the need for masking passwords and other sensitive information in request/response headers and payload.

Is it something that is supported out of the box for spring-cloud-sleuth or does it need to be configured programmatically by something that spring-cloud-sleuth provides?

Comment: Hi! What does it have to do with Sleuth? Sleuth just adds tracing information in the headers? Do you want to obfuscate those?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SpanAdjusters` to go through the contents of a span and remove / obfuscate whatever pieces you need